# Sending raw http headers

Tags: c, http, sockets, request, response

I have the following raw HTTP request:

```
GET http://www.google.ie/ HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google.ie
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encod...
```

I'm trying to send this from my localhost. Could someone point me in the right direction as to how I might do this in C or C++?

I'm currently looking at sockets, but it's not really working.

```
   int sockfdi, portnoi, ni;
   struct sockaddr_in serv_addri;
   struct hostent *serveri;
   portnoi =80;

   sockfdi = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
   if (sockfdi < 0){
        error("***ERROR opening socket");
   }
   serveri = gethostbyname("172.16.1.218");
   if (serveri == NULL){
       fprintf(stderr,"***ERROR, no such host\n");
       exit(0);
   }

   bzero((char *) &serv_addri, sizeof(serv_addri));
   serv_addri.sin_family = AF_INET;
   bcopy((char *)serveri->h_addr, (char *)&serv_addri.sin_addr.s_addr, serveri->h_length);
   serv_addri.sin_port = htons(portnoi);
   if (connect(sockfdi,(struct sockaddr *) &serv_addri,sizeof(serv_addri)) < 0){
       error("***ERROR connecting");
   }
   printf("Please enter the message: ");
   bzero(buffer,256);
```

Comment: "It's not really working" is a very bad problem description. Please tell us exactly what is not working/erroring out. BTW: I edited the headers you posted - please be very careful, HTTP headers have a very specific format that needs to be followed to the letter (especially the line endings).

Comment: Hi Mat, yes thanks for the edit. The problem is that error("***ERROR connecting") keeps triggering and I don't know how to get to the bottom of it. I've tried changing "localhost" to "127.0.0.1" too.

Comment: Use `perror` (or at least print the `errno`) so you have an idea about what's wrong.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using perror through a custom "error" function void error(const char *msg){ perror(msg); exit(1);} perror returns `***ERROR connecting: Connection refused`

Comment: Then check that there is indeed a server listening on 172.16.1.218:80,  and that you are not blocked (by a firewall for instance). Check with plain telnet.

Comment: Mmm... Eh I don't have a server running. I assumed it would simply get the request from the web? Maybe this is something I need to think about some more. Do you have any more suggestions?

Comment: If nothing is listening on that IP/port, there is no way you're going to connect to it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try using [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) instead of sockets:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(void)
{
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;
  struct curl_slist *headers = NULL;

  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Host: www.google.ie");
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0");
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5");
    /* Add more headers here */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.google.ie/");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    /* always cleanup */ 
    curl_slist_free_all(headers);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi, many thanks for your reply. I think this is exactly what I need. How do I print the response headers? I'm googling away trying to find out at the moment.

Comment: Check out the [curl_easy_setopt() API documentation](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html). You can set a callback function with the CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION option. The callback should match this prototype: size_t function( void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userdata);

Comment: In addition to handling the headers, you should also use the CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION option to assign a callback function that handles the response body data from the request (i.e. the HTML page that gets returned), since by default, curl_easy_perform() will print the body on stdout leaving you with a mess of HTML in your output.